# Issues migrating (no entries/channels/fields/template files)

Tags: channel-entries, channel, migration, template-manager

Duplicating/ Migrating an EE site (used EERelocate)

Template files:

- updated template file locations
- everything is writable; e.g., 666/777
- followed all the migration walkthrough on ElisLab site - Won't let me
  sync the template files (no options appear - just blank)

Channel Entries:

- No idea what to do here...? Imported DB, don't see anything

Channels/Channel Fields:

- None of my channels or fields are showing up

I've never had to migrate/duplicate an EE site before. I've followed everything I can... Totally stuck.

Comment: did you pull down a copy of the config and database files before the migration?

Comment: @TadWard Yes, sir.

Comment: One thing I would check is to make sure that you exported the entire database and not just a portion of it. If it was working properly in its old environment but not in the new one, then either the paths are wrong or some of the data didn't make it over.

Answer (score 0):

Read this tutorial, may it will help: http://www.creat-ee.com/tutorials/more/migrating_your_ee_site_to_live_server